# Vue-SweetAlert2のポップアップ内で複数のユーザーインプットを読み取り、その内のいくつかを1つのオブジェクトとして保存するには？

Tags: vue.js

現在、下記コード・添付画像のような、ユーザー情報を入力してもらうポップアップを作っています。

```
<template>
      <v-btn class="create-button" color="yellow" @click="alertDisplay">Create</v-btn>

    <br/>

    <p>Test result of createCustomer: {{ createdCustomer }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        createdCustomer: null
      }
    },
    methods: {
      async alertDisplay() {

        const {value: formValues} = await this.$swal.fire({
            title: 'Create private customer',
            html: '<input id="swal-input1" class="swal2-input" placeholder="Customer Number">' +
                '<select id="swal-input2" class="swal2-input"> <option value="fi_FI">fi_FI</option> <option value="sv_SE">sv_SE</option> </select>'
                 + 
                '<input id="swal-input3" class="swal2-input" placeholder="regNo">' +
                '<input v-model="createdCustomer.address.street" id="swal-input4" class="swal2-input" placeholder="Address (street)">' +
                '<input v-model="createdCustomer.address.city" id="swal-input5" class="swal2-input" placeholder="Address (city)">' +
                '<input v-model="createdCustomer.address.country" id="swal-input6" class="swal2-input" placeholder="Address (country)">' +
                '<input v-model="createdCustomer.address.region" id="swal-input7" class="swal2-input" placeholder="Address (region)">' +
                '<input v-model="createdCustomer.address.zipCode" id="swal-input8" class="swal2-input" placeholder="Address (zipCode)">' +
                '<input id="swal-input9" class="swal2-input" placeholder="First Name">' +
                '<input id="swal-input10" class="swal2-input" placeholder="Last Name">'
                ,
            focusConfirm: false,
            preConfirm: () => {
                return [
                    document.getElementById('swal-input1').value,
                    document.getElementById('swal-input2').value,
                    document.getElementById('swal-input3').value,
                    document.getElementById('swal-input4').value,
                    document.getElementById('swal-input5').value,
                    document.getElementById('swal-input6').value,
                    document.getElementById('swal-input7').value,
                    document.getElementById('swal-input8').value,
                    document.getElementById('swal-input9').value,
                    document.getElementById('swal-input10').value
                ]    

            }
        })
        if (formValues) {
            this.createdCustomer = formValues;
            console.log('the content of this.createdCustomer');
            console.log(this.createdCustomer);
            console.log('the content of this.createdCustomer.address');
            console.log(this.createdCustomer.address);
        }   
      }
  }
</script>
```

[image: multiple inputs]

ただ複数の項目を入力してもらう事だけなら今のコードのままでもできるのですが、「アドレス（住所）」の部分に関しては単なる「文字列」ではなく、下記コードのような複数の文字列からなる「オブジェクト型」として保存したいです。

```
"address": {
    "street": "string",
    "city": "string",
    "country": "string",
    "region": "string",
    "zipCode": "string"
}
```

今の所、HTMLとpreConfirm parametersを使って入力項目をポップアップ内に表示させているのですが、上記のようなオブジェクト型でユーザーのアドレス（住所）を保存したい場合、どのようにすれば良いのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

一応解決したので、備忘録も兼ねて追記しておきます。

問題だったのは、

```
if (formValues) {
            this.createdCustomer = formValues;
            console.log('the content of this.createdCustomer');
            console.log(this.createdCustomer);
            console.log('the content of this.createdCustomer.address');
            console.log(this.createdCustomer.address);
        }
```

の`this.createdCustomer = formValues;`という部分でした。
この1行のせいで、データが10個の個別のインプットとして保存され、`formValues`の中身のaddressの部分がオブジェクト型ではなく単なる文字列型の配列として`this.createdCustomer`に格納されてしまっていました。

これを解決するために行ったことは以下の2つです。

1. `createdCustomer`をオブジェクト型で宣言する事
2. `formValues`のインデックスを1つずつ参照して値を`this.createdCustomer`に渡す事（***←これに全然気づきませんでした***）

1に関しては、`createdCustomer`を次のように宣言しました。

```
data() {
      return {
        createdCustomer: {
          customerNumber: null,
          locale: null,
          regNo: null,
          address: {
            street: null,
            city: null,
            country: null,
            region: null,
            zipCode: null
          },
          firstName: null,
          lastName: null
        }
      }
    },
```

2に関しては、次のようにインデックスを1つずつ参照しました。

```
if (formValues) {
            //this.createdCustomer = formValues;   // this one line overwrote the entire createdCustomer object, which was the root of the problem
            this.createdCustomer.customerNumber = formValues[0];
            this.createdCustomer.locale = formValues[1];
            this.createdCustomer.regNo = formValues[2];
            this.createdCustomer.address.street = formValues[3];
            this.createdCustomer.address.city = formValues[4];
            this.createdCustomer.address.country = formValues[5];
            this.createdCustomer.address.region = formValues[6];
            this.createdCustomer.address.zipCode = formValues[7];
            this.createdCustomer.firstName = formValues[8];
            this.createdCustomer.lastName = formValues[9];

            console.log('the content of this.createdCustomer.address');
            console.log(this.createdCustomer.address);

            console.log('the content of this.createdCustomer.address.street');
            console.log(this.createdCustomer.address.street);

        }
```

その結果、アドレスがちゃんと「アドレスオブジェクト型」で保存され、出力結果も期待した通りとなりました。

```
Test result of createCustomer: { "customerNumber": "JS1", "locale": "fi_FI", "regNo": "123ABC", "address": { "street": "stackoverflow st 12", "city": "San Francisco", "country": "USA", "region": "California", "zipCode": "12345" }, "firstName": "Shinichi", "lastName": "Takagi" }
```

[image: Successful]